# Can Callout be combined with Evaluated->True in Plot?

Tags: plotting, labeling

I would like to use `Callout` (Mathematica 11) in a `Plot` where `Evaluated -> True` is used.

```
Plot[x^# & /@ {1, 2, 3}, {x, -10, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

produces a plot with three curves.

But

```
Plot[Callout[x^#, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, {x, -10, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

gives an empty plot.

However,

```
Plot[{Callout[x, 1], Callout[x^2, 2], Callout[x^3, 3]}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

works as expected.

Is there an easy way to map `Callout` over a list of functions in `Plot`?

Comment: I think "why `Evaluated->True` fails in this case" is a more interesting question. Look forward to an answer addressing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Module[{x}, Plot[Evaluate[Callout[x^#, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}], {x, -10, 10}] ]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice @Kuba! `Plot[Evaluate[Callout[\[FormalX]^#, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}], {\[FormalX], -10, 10}]` works, too. Any idea why?

Comment: @grbl why not? :) I put `Module` just in case. It doesn't do anything but protecting in case of `x` being assigned outside.